# Right click is not disabling when click on video player which is uploaded from youtube

Tags: jquery

I uploaded video from local computer. And using this code disable right click on video.

**Code:**

```
$("video").bind("contextmenu",function() 
  {
     return false;
});
```

But these line of code is not working when uploading video from `YouTube`.

Comment: are you uploading or just loading video from youtube url???

Comment: I am just loading video using video url

Answer (score 1):

if you use bind() do follow in below

```
$('video').bind("contextmenu", function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

or

```
$(document).bind("contextmenu",function(e){
    return false;
});
```

also you can use on() do follow in below

```
$("video").on("contextmenu",function(e){
    return false;
});
```

Comment: These solutions are working if uploading video from computer. but it is not working  if loading video using YouTube video url.